# Jquery .animate not working

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/KrA3D/

I tried to run this both locally and in the jsfiddle without success. Am I missing something? I want to make this image move to the right.

HTML

```
<div id="game">
    <img id="asd" src="http://i.imgur.com/ApuSWMC.png" alt="torch">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#asd').click(function () {

        $('#asd').animate({
            left: "+=100px"
        }, 'fast');

    });

});
```

I thought it has to do with the selector, tried both by `id` and `img`, tried changing it to a `div`, without success. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must position the element (relatively or absolutely) before you can change its position:

```
#asd {
    position: absolute; // or position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/KrA3D/1/

Answer (score 1):

yes, position absolute or relative will work here to the id asd.